# Sub menu on hover over navbar link in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to to implement a feature in my bootstrap project like whenever someone will hover over my one of navbar links, it will display a detailed menu vertically like a menu in image below

[image]

I know how to make dropdown on hover over navbar link, but how can i populate this type of sub menu on hover.
Is already there any tutorial or example exists then do share with me.
If not then share idea!

Thanks!

Html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: See [bootstrap-menu.com](https://bootstrap-menu.com) for several examples using Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


 <style>
   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
   }
  .mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  }
 .mega-dropdown-menu {
   padding: 20px 0px;
   width: 100%;
   box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  }
 .mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }
 .mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
 }
 .mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 3px 5px;
 }
 .mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
 .mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  .mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
   font-size: 18px;
    color: #ff3546;
   padding: 5px 60px 5px 5px;
   line-height: 30px;
   }

  .carousel-control {
    width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   top: -35px;

 }
    .left.carousel-control {
    right: 30px;
   left: inherit;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
 .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
   font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  </style>




<div class="container">
```

Toggle navigation
            
            
            
        
        My Store

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Men <span class="caret"></span></a>              
            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Men Collection</li>                            
                        <div id="menCollection" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ff3546/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>
                                <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4>                                        
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>       
                            </div><!-- End Item -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>
                                <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4>                                        
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>        
                            </div><!-- End Item -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>
                                <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4>                                        
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>      
                            </div><!-- End Item -->                                
                          </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                          <!-- Controls -->
                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#menCollection" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#menCollection" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                        </div><!-- /.carousel -->
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Features</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Carousel Control</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Left & Right Navigation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Four Columns Grid</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Fonts</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Glyphicon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Google Fonts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Plus</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Navbar Inverse</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>                            
                        <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>                          
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Much more</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Easy to Customize</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Custom Fonts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Slide down on Hover</a></li>                         
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>               
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Women <span class="caret"></span></a>                
            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Features</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Carousel Control</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Left & Right Navigation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Four Columns Grid</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Fonts</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Glyphicon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Google Fonts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Plus</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Navbar Inverse</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>                            
                        <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>                          
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Much more</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Easy to Customize</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Custom Fonts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Slide down on Hover</a></li>                         
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Women Collection</li>                            
                        <div id="womenCollection" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/3498db/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 1"></a>
                                <h4><small>Summer dress floral prints</small></h4>                                        
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>       
                            </div><!-- End Item -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/ff3546/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 2"></a>
                                <h4><small>Gold sandals with shiny touch</small></h4>                                        
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">9,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>        
                            </div><!-- End Item -->
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/254x150/2ecc71/f5f5f5/&text=New+Collection" class="img-responsive" alt="product 3"></a>
                                <h4><small>Denin jacket stamped</small></h4>                                        
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">49,99 €</button> <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add to Wishlist</button>      
                            </div><!-- End Item -->                                
                          </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                          <!-- Controls -->
                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#womenCollection" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#womenCollection" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                        </div><!-- /.carousel -->
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">View all Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>               
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Store locator</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">My account <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">My cart (0) items</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
```

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown("400");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');        
    },
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');       
       }
     );
  });
 </script>
```

for more visite [enter link description here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-slide-down-on-hover-with-carousel)

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this, You can use below code :

`HTML` :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                <a href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">
                    <li class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Sword of Truth</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><img class"img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Panda</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Button dropdowns</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                </ul>

            </li>
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">
                    <li class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Sword of Truths</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Theme/Character</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">by brand</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><img class"img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                </ul>

            </li>

      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                <a href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                <a href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Sword of Truths</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Theme/Character</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">by brand</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><img class"img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
<li class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Sword of Truths</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Theme/Character</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">by brand</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><img class"img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x150"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>



        </ul>

    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</nav>
```

`CSS` :

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

body{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
}
.dropdown-large {
  position: static !important;
}
.dropdown-menu-large {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight:300;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li ul > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu-large {
    margin-left: 0 ;
    margin-right: 0 ;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large > li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large > li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;
  }
}
```

Fiddle is here [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/t6gq52cm/)

Comment: awsome !
But how can i open the provided sub menu on hover over the link ??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/t6gq52cm/1/
Check this link now..
I applied this on hover.. :)
Hope it helps you

Comment: That's great Cheers :)

Comment: Hey !
I am working on this navbar   https://codyhouse.co/demo/3d-rotating-navigation/#0 and trying to applying your solution but it's not properly working.
Can you help me !

Answer (score 1):

This may be an option, you just need to adjust the margin and padding to your needs.

Hope it helps. ;)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.dropdown-menu-fixed {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu-fixed > ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 1rem 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu-fixed > ul li {
  padding: 3px 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu-fixed a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-fixed > ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 1rem 60px;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Personal 
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fixed">

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
              <li><a class="small" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="small" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
              <li><a class="small" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="small" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
              <li><a class="small" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="small" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: can i have the same effect on hover over link item?
What can i do for that ?

Comment: I made an update to my post and Added the hover style to the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work for desktop as well as mobile views:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
    function () {
                if (!$($(this).parents()[3]).find('.navbar-toggle').is(":visible"))               {
                    $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
                }
            },
            function () {
                if (!$($(this).parents()[3]).find('.navbar-toggle').is(":visible"))                 {
                    $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
                }
            }
      );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```